# how do I use propositional equivalence laws to simplify?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have two statements that are supposed to simplify to the same answer:

1) (not(p or q) or not(p or not q))

2) ((p or q) implies (not p and q))

how do these simplify using the equivalence laws of propositional logic into the same answer? I have found using truth tables I get (not P) for both, but I cannot figure out how using the laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these derivations will help:

**1)**

$$\begin{align}
\neg (p \lor q) \lor \neg(p \lor \neg q) &\iff \neg((p\lor q) \land (p\lor \neg q) ) \tag{De Morgan} \\
&\iff \neg(p \land( q \lor \neg q) ) \tag{$\land$ distributes over $\lor$} \\
&\iff \neg(p) \tag{$A \land \sf{True} \iff A$} \\
&= \neg p \\
\end{align}$$

**2)**

$$\begin{align}
(p \lor q) \to (\neg p \land q) &\iff \neg(p \lor q) \lor (\neg p \land q) \tag{$A\to B\iff \neg A\lor B$} \\
&\iff (\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land q) \tag{De Morgan} \\
&\iff \neg p \land (\neg q \lor  q) \tag{$\land$ distributes over $\lor$} \\
&\iff \neg p  \tag{$A \land \sf{True} \iff A$} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: ok thank you so much. this makes much more sense I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to give it a vote &/or "accept" it -- tips appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

1a) we have "(not(p or q) or not(p or not q)) "

Rule:  A or B $\iff$ not (A and B)

so

NOT(not not (p or q) and not not (p or not q))

or

NOT((p or q) and (p or not q))

1b)  Rule:  (A or B) and (A or -B) $\iff$ A

so we have

NOT p

2a) we have "((p or q) implies (not p and q))"

Rule: A implies B $\iff$ not(A and not B)

so

not ((p or q) and not (not p and q))

2b) Rule:  not (A and B) $\iff$ (not A or not B) so

not((p or q) and (not not p or not q))

or

not((p or q) and  (p or not q))

2c) Rule:  (A or B) and (A or not B) $\iff$ A

so

not (p)

Comment: what laws did you use?

Comment: can you please explain your steps because I'm not understanding how you simplified that

Comment: I don't know the names of the laws.  Let me write the post.  The way I wrote it is unclear.